# Incorrect bread crumb in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico, breadcrumbs

I copy my page or copy link with product which have some bread crumb, but after that bread crumb is changed but i want that bread crumb not changed. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're copying the page to another location in the content tree it will have the new URL as the breadcrumb and not the old one from the existing page.

If your page will have the same exact content, I'd suggest using a Linked Page as you can get the parent linked page's URL.  I don't believe this solves your problem using the breadcrumb webpart but you can use a repeater or a universal viewer to get similar results.

Comment: I used a Linked Page, my url has not change but breadCrumb is shanged. This is the main problem

Comment: The breadcrumbs uses the current location in the content tree.  As I mentioned this will not get you what you want.  You will need to use a repeater or a universal viewer to get the linked page parent url because you can use the method `GetDocumentUrl(Eval<int>("DocumentID"))` to get the correct URL.